# Ubuntu 18 custom boot script to run on every boot, created manually symbolic link to the script, but still not executed

Tags: boot, 18.04, init.d

I am trying to start myscript in Ubuntu 18.04, to be executed in the boot up. For this i did the below

```
1) myscript is copied to /etc/init.d with proper permission as +x
2) created symbolic link using ln -s in /etc/rc5.d
```

confirmed the runlevel is 5, by running runlevel.
but after i reboot, then do not see my script getting executed ? is there anything else i need to do other than creating the soft link int eh rcX.d folder ?

Answer (score 0):

After reading and google figured out how to do it, please check link
[ubuntu-1804-running-script-at-boot](http://dinomycle.blogspot.com/2020/06/ubuntu-1804-running-script-at-boot.html)